# Dependencies for VC++ CLR 2012 project

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio-2012

So, my problem is the for my application I cannot require the user to install anything except .net 4, I cannot ask them to install the C++ redistribute. Is there any way to give a list of files my application depends on so I can determine what files are missing on stock windows 7 and xp machines. Also how do I go about embedding the required DLLs into the exe?

Thanks.

Edit: Dependency walker doesn't seem to help, even after I move the files it says are missing the application fails to run.

Comment: It is just another file to copy along with the project's executables.  If that's a insurmountable problem then you'll have to stop using C++/CLI.

Comment: Use installer, like InnoSetup, to distribute your .exe along with all needed dlls. Or your installer can incorporate msvcr2012 package and launch its installation quitely.

Answer (score 0):

Run Dependency Walker in profiling mode. It's of course possible that your application tries to load a custom ".foo" file, and exits if that fails. That is your own application logic, and we can't help with that. The only dependencies that Windows knows are DLLs, and those are checked by Dependency Walker.